# Set predefined values from parent object while creating child object in master detail relationship

Tags: master-detail, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have master detail relationship between Opportunity and Work Order. There is Work Order related list in Opportunity. On clicking 'New' in related list, I want to prepopulate some fields using Opportunity values in lightning. The user must be able to change the predefined values if needed.

On researching, I found out that it can be done using Quick Actions. [More information](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.predefined_field_values.htm&type=5). The problem is that I won't be able to use the 'New' button of related list to create new Work Order if I am using Quick Action. Also, I won't be able to use the existing page layout.

I was looking into other ways to prepopulate field values while creating a record but did not find any. Did I miss something? Please guide.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL hacking can be used to achieve the functionality. Check the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm).

**Code:**

```
/lightning/o/Account/new?defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},
    OwnerId={!Account.OwnerId},
    AccountNumber={!Account.AccountNumber},
    NumberOfEmployees=35000,
    CustomCheckbox__c={!IF(Account.SomeCheckbox__c, true, false)}
```

Note that there should not be spaces or carriage returns in the URL.

[Detailed explanation](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-for-lightning-tutorial/).